# How to setup more than one project in docker?

Tags: magento2, base-url, docker

I have successfully installed Magento 2 with sample data using [Docker](https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2)

everything works fine but I have below question.

- Magento 2 project Base URL is 127.0.0.1 How can I change this URL?
- What if I want to add more than one project what kind of changes is required 
  for that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

For question number 1:

— You can go to **`docker-compose`** file and look for **apache** service then change **`port`** to something like **`8085:80`** then your project **baseURL** would be like **`127.0.0.1:8085`** or **`http://localhost:8085/`**

For question number 2:

— I believe, 1 docker file for 1 project only. Otherwise, you need to create another docker file for another project.

Comment: Let me check, If it works I will accept your answer

Comment: Suppose I want my project URL like http://127.0.0.1/mylatestproject//  than where I want to make changes? @fmsthird

Comment: I think the best way to do this (if you are on windows OS) is to edit `hosts` file , from there you can define the name of your custom baseURL . let say, 127.0.0.1  mylatestproject . then you can access your project from web typing **mylatestproject**

Answer (score 2):

I know maybe this isn't the answer you are expected but I have a different docker compose file for each project. Once I've finished working on one project I `docker-compose down -v` project, switch to my working copy in my other project and `docker-compose up -d`

Each project has it's own set of containers which build up a lamp stack. So own db container. But also that way I've got plenty of resouce free for IDE etc

But also that way you're not having to make config changes to switch between stacks. Plus they can all have same url (magento2.docker) and I've got 1 host file entry. Lazy but as docker is dev for me it's okay to take shortcuts.

Docker compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

And file like this for each project

https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2/blob/master/docker-compose.yml